# Apply ninject interceptor to multiple bindings

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I'm currently working with a large set of bindings that are being setup in an ASP.NET web API solution and for the most part WhenInjectedInto is being used with Ninject. 
To apply my logging aspect I have to add to each binding

`.Intercept().With<LoggingAspect>();`
eg

```
Bind<IMyServiceClass>().To<MyService>()
.WhenInjectedInto<SomeOtherClass>()
.Intercept().With<LoggingAspect>();;
```

which is a bit tiresome, especially when I want to switch between interception and non interception and I have over 100 bindings like this.

Is there a way to bind the loggingaspect interceptor to all bindings held in ninject?

or perhaps I should apply the interceptor to everything and then just have the interceptor do a check and either run interception code or not?

Comment: how about creating the bindings by convention? this way you'd only need to adapt the convention. How do you currently know whether the type should be intercepted or not?

Comment: I want to intercept everything so as I'm timing method calls to find slow running calls and also what parameters were used at the time. It all works fine but I'm trying to find a neater way of doing it. Convention would be okay but the way the API was designed means it uses .WhenInjectedInto all over the place which makes it difficult to use convention

Answer (score 2):

Been a while since I dealt with Ninject, but it is possible to Intercept at the Kernel level:

`kernel.Intercept(context => true).With<LoggerInterceptor>();`

This will apply to all services registered in the kernel.

You'll need to install either `Ninject.Extensions.Interception.DynamicProxy` or `Ninject.Extensions.Interception.Linfu` from NuGet.

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried it but keeps moaning about a sealed class:

Could not load type 'Castle.Proxies.Func`1Proxy' from assembly 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a621a9e7e5c32e69' because the parent type is sealed.

Comment: you won't be able to intercept on that class, no matter what you're going to do. So either exclude it (adapt the `.Intercept(context => true)` part to suit your needs) or unseal the class...